# Send message to phone number not @username using Telegram Bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Is this possible to send message to phone number not @username using telegram bot?

If answer is No, I have to say I have telegram account without @username and several days ago I got message from a Bot, how this is possible?

Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: It is NOT possible for a bot to send messages to a phone number. As far as I know, it is also NOT possible to send to a `@username`, unless it is a `@channel_username`.

A bot sends messages by `user_id`. It can know your `user_id` only if you have send it a message first. If you have never talked to a bot, but find it send you a message, the only way I can think of that happening is through a group chat or channel.

Answer (score 4):

its not possible send message to phone number or username. you can only send message by ID.

i almost try every thing.(group chat or channel) the only way, bot can send a message to the user is the user start the conversation.

Comment: What if user installed app but i only do have the username ?

Comment: it is possible, recently I received message directly on my telegram for confirmation of my phone number from a site! but i couldn't find how!

Comment: dear @FoadTahmasebi. its not possible to send the message by phone number in telegram bot api. what you saw is the new feature called telegram login. its so simple. here you can read about that: https://telegram.org/blog/login

Comment: @David, thank you for your answer, I know what is telegram login for website. I'm sorry, maybe I shouldn't comment here, it's not a bot, it is sending a message directly from a phone number. If you want to test it, signup mql5.com and confirm your phone number by telegram in your profile section.

Comment: Thanks for sharing dear @FoadTahmasebi. i check the website. they are using telegram api. its not bot api.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible to do that, Because I used a tool to send messages to phone number. I think it may be add phone number to your contacts, and then send message. If you interested, you can try this tool for test:https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/teleplus-multi-accounts-s/ihopneheidomphlibjllfheciogojmbk

Answer (score -5):

i can send message in to telegram channel with:

https://api.telegram.org/bot"your token"/sendMessage?chat_id="your chat public link as @msg"&text=123

wold replaced "your token" with token
and replaced "your chat public link as @msg" with chanel name

important:
your bot must be as administrator of your chanel

Comment: This is not the target of the question at all. This send public message to all the members of the channel!